# How to give 2 backref to the same table while using the same column for the foreign key?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

like I have a user table and a post table and the post table have to column posted_by and edited_by which are the foreign key referencing the same user_id column in the user table... so how to do it SQL Alchemy and also I want my relationship should be mentioned at parent table.

Comment: The documentation would be a good place to start. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I interpreted your question correctly, but I did, here is a solution I created for you.

```
class Table1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table2 = db.relationship('Table2', backref=db.backref('table1'), lazy=True)
    table3 = db.relationship('Table3', backref=db.backref('table1'), lazy=True)
    
class Table2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table1.id'), nullable=False)

class Table2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table3'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table1.id'), nullable=False)
```

Comment: Did this answer help you?